# Concatenate a Text String to the End of Specific Values (MS ACCESS)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I need to add "-CLOSED" the end of certain Job Numbers in an Access Query. I can add it to one at a time but I need to do it for thousands of values. I'm not sure of the syntax to add more than one value in the WHERE clause.

```
UPDATE t_loc
SET t_loc.loc = t_loc.loc & "-CLOSED"
WHERE t_loc.loc = 'M14001' AND 'M14003'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE t_loc.loc = 'M14001' AND 'M14003'` Will not work because you are saying that the column will have both of those values in the same column (I'm not sure if this is correct syntax in MS Access).

If you want to set it for multiple columns then you will need to check if that column contains the specific values. Here is a short way of how to set it for multiple values:

```
UPDATE t_loc
SET t_loc.loc = t_loc.loc & "-CLOSED"
WHERE t_loc.loc IN ('M14001', 'M14003')
```

If you want to add more then you can simply add another value within the parentheses. But since you are talking about thousands of values then you will be better off have a temp table containing the values then changing it to:

```
UPDATE t_loc
SET t_loc.loc = t_loc.loc & "-CLOSED"
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT temploc.val
    FROM temploc
    WHERE temploc.val = t_loc.loc
)
```

I chose to use `EXISTS` in the second query instead of `IN` because it is faster when the inner select returns 1 row when it exists instead of returning all the rows on each condition check.